# Can't open gitk

Tags: macos, gitk

I can't open gitk[image: Error]

shows some error about no authorization, this happen because once I couldn't open and I try to install from brew

now if I type

```
type -a git
```

shows

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if, as [in here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/400054), you need to enable `Automation / Terminal / System Events.app`:

[image: Automation]

Or reset all permissions you've set on AppleEvents using [`tccutil`](https://ss64.com/osx/tccutil.html):

```
tccutil reset AppleEvents
```